# filtering an array of objects in javascript using .filter()

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, filter

I want to filter an array of objects in javascript ideally using the filter method using the sector values

**Sample Input**

```
[
    {
        "columns": {
            "ccy": {
                "style": 7,
                "value": "EUR",
                "formatted_value": "EUR",
                "error": null
            },
            "country": {
                "style": 7,
                "value": "France",
                "formatted_value": "France",
                "error": null
            },
            "sector": {
                "style": 7,
                "value": "Utilities",
                "formatted_value": "Utilities",
                "error": null
            },
            "isin": {
                "style": 7,
                "value": "FR0011374099",
                "formatted_value": "FR0011374099",
                "error": null
            },
            "instrument": {
                "style": 7,
                "value": "AF 6.25 18Jan18",
                "formatted_value": "AF 6.25 18Jan18",
                "error": null
            },
            "price": {
                "style": 8,
                "value": 1.08,
                "formatted_value": "1.08",
                "error": null
            },
            "bid": {
                "style": 9,
                "value": 1,
                "formatted_value": "1.000",
                "error": null
            },
            "ask": {
                "style": 9,
                "value": 1.15,
                "formatted_value": "1.150",
                "error": null
            },
            "coupon": {
                "style": 10,
                "value": 0.01,
                "formatted_value": "1.00%",
                "error": null
            },
            "date": {
                "style": 11,
                "value": 43118,
                "formatted_value": "18-Jan-2018 00:00:00",
                "error": null
            },
            "rating": {
                "style": 5,
                "value": "C",
                "formatted_value": "C",
                "error": null
            },
            "position": {
                "style": 7,
                "value": null,
                "formatted_value": null,
                "error": null
            },
            "nav": {
                "style": 12,
                "value": null,
                "formatted_value": null,
                "error": null
            }
        },
        "index": 4
    },
    {
        "columns": {
            "ccy": {
                "style": 0,
                "value": "EUR",
                "formatted_value": "EUR",
                "error": null
            },
            "country": {
                "style": 0,
                "value": "France",
                "formatted_value": "France",
                "error": null
            },
            "sector": {
                "style": 0,
                "value": "Transport",
                "formatted_value": "Transport",
                "error": null
            },
            "isin": {
                "style": 0,
                "value": "FR0010804500",
                "formatted_value": "FR0010804500",
                "error": null
            },
            "instrument": {
                "style": 0,
                "value": "AREVAG 4.875 23Sep24",
                "formatted_value": "AREVAG 4.875 23Sep24",
                "error": null
            },
            "price": {
                "style": 1,
                "value": 0.86,
                "formatted_value": "0.86",
                "error": null
            },
            "bid": {
                "style": 2,
                "value": 0.79,
                "formatted_value": "0.790",
                "error": null
            },
            "ask": {
                "style": 2,
                "value": 0.94,
                "formatted_value": "0.940",
                "error": null
            },
            "coupon": {
                "style": 3,
                "value": 0.04875,
                "formatted_value": "4.88%",
                "error": null
            },
            "date": {
                "style": 4,
                "value": 44203.5243055556,
                "formatted_value": "07-Jan-2021 12:35:00",
                "error": null
            },
            "rating": {
                "style": 5,
                "value": "NR",
                "formatted_value": "NR",
                "error": null
            },
            "position": {
                "style": 0,
                "value": null,
                "formatted_value": null,
                "error": null
            },
            "nav": {
                "style": 6,
                "value": null,
                "formatted_value": null,
                "error": null
            }
        },
        "index": 5
    },
    {
        "columns": {
            "ccy": {
                "style": 7,
                "value": "EUR",
                "formatted_value": "EUR",
                "error": null
            },
            "country": {
                "style": 7,
                "value": "France",
                "formatted_value": "France",
                "error": null
            },
            "sector": {
                "style": 7,
                "value": "Transport",
                "formatted_value": "Transport",
                "error": null
            },
            "isin": {
                "style": 7,
                "value": "FR0011791391",
                "formatted_value": "FR0011791391",
                "error": null
            },
            "instrument": {
                "style": 7,
                "value": "AREVAG 3.125 20Mar23",
                "formatted_value": "AREVAG 3.125 20Mar23",
                "error": null
            },
            "price": {
                "style": 8,
                "value": 0.83,
                "formatted_value": "0.83",
                "error": null
            },
            "bid": {
                "style": 9,
                "value": 1.333,
                "formatted_value": "1.333",
                "error": null
            },
            "ask": {
                "style": 9,
                "value": 0.9,
                "formatted_value": "0.900",
                "error": null
            },
            "coupon": {
                "style": 10,
                "value": 0.001,
                "formatted_value": "0.10%",
                "error": null
            },
            "date": {
                "style": 11,
                "value": 45731,
                "formatted_value": "15-Mar-2025 00:00:00",
                "error": null
            },
            "rating": {
                "style": 5,
                "value": "BB",
                "formatted_value": "BB",
                "error": null
            },
            "position": {
                "style": 7,
                "value": null,
                "formatted_value": null,
                "error": null
            },
            "nav": {
                "style": 12,
                "value": null,
                "formatted_value": null,
                "error": null
            }
        },
        "index": 6
    }
]
```

**Expected Output: (Utilities sector)**

```
[
    {
        "columns": {
            "ccy": {
                "style": 7,
                "value": "EUR",
                "formatted_value": "EUR",
                "error": null
            },
            "country": {
                "style": 7,
                "value": "France",
                "formatted_value": "France",
                "error": null
            },
            "sector": {
                "style": 7,
                "value": "Utilities",
                "formatted_value": "Utilities",
                "error": null
            },
            "isin": {
                "style": 7,
                "value": "FR0011374099",
                "formatted_value": "FR0011374099",
                "error": null
            },
            "instrument": {
                "style": 7,
                "value": "AF 6.25 18Jan18",
                "formatted_value": "AF 6.25 18Jan18",
                "error": null
            },
            "price": {
                "style": 8,
                "value": 1.08,
                "formatted_value": "1.08",
                "error": null
            },
            "bid": {
                "style": 9,
                "value": 1,
                "formatted_value": "1.000",
                "error": null
            },
            "ask": {
                "style": 9,
                "value": 1.15,
                "formatted_value": "1.150",
                "error": null
            },
            "coupon": {
                "style": 10,
                "value": 0.01,
                "formatted_value": "1.00%",
                "error": null
            },
            "date": {
                "style": 11,
                "value": 43118,
                "formatted_value": "18-Jan-2018 00:00:00",
                "error": null
            },
            "rating": {
                "style": 5,
                "value": "C",
                "formatted_value": "C",
                "error": null
            },
            "position": {
                "style": 7,
                "value": null,
                "formatted_value": null,
                "error": null
            },
            "nav": {
                "style": 12,
                "value": null,
                "formatted_value": null,
                "error": null
            }
        },
        "index": 4
    }
  }
]
```

What I've tried:

```
const myFilteredData = myUnfilteredData.filter((data) => data.sector.value === 'Utilities');
```

My confusion is arising from the structure of the data I am working with, it's an array of objects like this.

I need to `.map` first and then `.filter` on the return of that map?

Comment: It isn't clear what do you want to filter. Sector Sales is not in your data. Could you please clarify

Comment: Also, you're passing `data` into your filter function, but never use it. Might you be looking for `data.sector` instead of `myUnfilteredData.sector`?

Comment: Given the sample data, your result would be an empty array. None of the objects have a sector with a formatted value of "Sales".

Comment: I have edited my example filter. Basically what I want to do it, filter over all the objects in the array, each object has another object with the key of "sector" and I want filter based on that objects key of "value" which can be "Utilities", "Industry", "Sales". If the sector object has a matching value, want to return that whole object into a new array.

Comment: @Udders you need to elaborate with an example showing the expected output

Comment: @MajedBadawi please see edit

Comment: None have "Sales", still unclear, please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Updated again, and if that were the case, then I would expect `[]` as a the retuned from the filter

Comment: You are missing the `columns` object in between: `.filter(data => data.columns.sector.value === 'Utilities')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sector` is inside `columns`:

```
const myFilteredData = myUnfilteredData.filter(data => 
  data.columns.sector.value === 'Utilities'
);
```

Answer (score -1):

The best that you can do is to provide new variable for your desired result and iterate the data array.

for example:

```
const result = [];

data.forEach(e => {
    if (e.columns.sector.value && e.columns.sector.value === 'Sales') {
        /**
            you can push what you want to map. for example
            result.push({
               columns: e.columns,
               sector: e.columns.sector.value
            })
        **/
        result.push(e);
    }
});
```

you can push to the new variable any object you want out from the original data. this way you only iterate your data array once.